# How to add currency format to Data Row in AspxPivotGrid by Programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to add currency format to Data Row in AspxPivotGrid table.
You can see the below picture,how it is displaying now. So I just want to display currency format to 3 fields (ExtendedPrice,ExtendedCost,Profit)

[image: Now how it is displaying]

This is my c# code:

```
if (i == 8 || i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 11)
{
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridField newF = new DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridField(names[i], PivotArea.DataArea);
    newF.ID = "field" + newF.FieldName;
    //newF.ValueFormat.FormatType=
    ASPxPivotGrid1.Fields.Add(newF);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this doc ([FormatInfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressUtilsFormatInfotopic)) I think it should be set like that:

```
newF.ValueFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric;
newF.ValueFormat.FormatString = "c2";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
newF.ValueFormat-FormatString = "c2";
newF.ValueFormat-FormatType = "Numeric";
```